# Google Maps V3 : Trigger map pan Event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We have trouble with firing the Map Events ... We tried the following code but the Map Pan Event is fired only very first time .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <style type="text/css">
            html { height: 100% }
            body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
            #map-canvas { height: 100% }
        </style>
        <script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<key>&sensor=false"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initialize() {
                var mouseDown;
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                    zoom: 8
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                        mapOptions);
                map.addListener("center_changed", function() {

                     //  alert("center_changed");
                     console.log("center_changed");

                });

                map.addListener("mouseup", function() {
                    this.mouseDown = false;
                  //   alert("mouseup");
                });

                map.addListener("mousedown", function() {
                    this.mouseDown = true;
                    // alert("mousedown");
                });
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

            /*     google.maps.event.addListener('dragend', function() {
             return function() {
             console.log("Drag Event Called");

             }
             });
             */


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please provide the idea to overcome this...

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Please provide me the answer .....

Comment: I don't see any "pan" event in your code, and I don't see any attempt to trigger events in the code. Maybe its just your English but please fix your question to be comprehensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this.

```
map.addListener("dragend", function() {

                    //  alert("center_changed");
                    count++;
                    console.log("center_changed"+count);
                   //ur method .....

               });
```

Comment: Although it is not necessary to declare map above `initialize()`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `map.addListener` you should try `google.maps.event.addDomListener` instead:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
    console.log('center changed');
});
```

Comment: Yeah, just realised that bit that you'd commented out in your code was the bit that you wanted help with. I've updated my answer with the `dragend` event instead. I recommend you use `addDomListener` as I believe it's the preferred method.